# `not a module` - error throws on interface assignment

Tags: typescript, angular6

I am trying to add the interface to my app component. getting error as `interface.ts is not a module` - hot to fix this.

my appComponent.ts:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Name } from "./interface";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name:Name = "CodeSandbox";
}
```

my interface.ts:

```
export interface Name {
  name: string;
}
```

What is wrong with my code? Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think import `path` should be `import { Name } from "./interfaces/interface";`

Comment: Ditto what @hrdkisback said, except I'm confused how the error would say `interface.ts` if the import was `./interfaces`. Is this the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

your interface file name must be match to your interface name.
so you must rename your interface file to my Name.ts:

```
export interface Name {
  name: string;
}
```

and

```
import { Name } from "./Name ";
```